# rosbag play - skip every Nth file

Tags: ros-melodic, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a bag with X images, and messages.

I want to test if rtabmap odometry can handle images at different frame rates (e.g. using half the frames)

Is it possible to play the bag in a way that skips every second frame, so I don't have to create a bag for every possible frame rate?

Thanks,
Avner

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315288/rosbag-play---skip-every-nth-file/) by [Avner](https://answers.ros.org/users/36789/avner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2019-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know of any way you can do this with the standard command line tools. However if you don't mind getting your hands dirty, you could use the [rosbag_api](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API) to write a simple node that published the sensor messages from a bag at the desired rate.

The example on the page I linked to prints every message out on the screen. But you would want to modify it so that it only publishes messages on the desired topic, and at the rate you want.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Avner](https://answers.ros.org/users/36789/avner/) on 2019-02-11**:
I definitely helps. thanks